# Magento2 : How to get home url in Knockout HTML template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

i want to get cart url in  Knockout HTML template magento 2

Comment: For which template are you looking for url?

Comment: i want to get store url in checkout/web/template

Comment: Have you define  js file for respective HTML template?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the relevant parts:

```
checkout.baseUrl
checkout.checkoutUrl
checkout.customerLoginUrl
checkout.removeItemUrl
checkout.shoppingCartUrl
checkout.updateItemQtyUrl

checkoutConfig.cartUrl
checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl
checkoutConfig.defaultSuccessPageUrl
checkoutConfig.forgotPasswordUrl
checkoutConfig.pageNotFoundUrl
checkoutConfig.registerUrl
checkoutConfig.staticBaseUrl
```

Reference : [Best Way Of Getting Base URL Inside KnockoutJS .html File](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189338/best-way-of-getting-base-url-inside-knockoutjs-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

See below code to get Cart url in Knockout HTML template in Magento2
**shoppingCartUrl**

See below example link to Cart page.

```
<a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'View Cart' --><!-- /ko --></span
</a>
```