# Best Way Of Getting Base URL Inside KnockoutJS .html File

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, html, knockoutjs, knockout

How can I get the base URL inside a KnockoutJS HTML file? See file below:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/<Filename>.html
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No am still looking for the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three parts to this, I will use the checkout authentication as an example but this should work in any KO/JS file that has `mage/url` as a dependency.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication.js
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/authentication.html
```

### Setting up the URL in the JS file

Add `mage/url` to the list of dependencies.

Add the following function to the JS file:

```
getBaseUrl: function() {
    return url.build('testing');
},
```

### Use Knockout to set the href

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }">Link here 2</a>
```

### Result

I had to clear Varnish and browser cache.

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/testing" data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }">Link here 2</a>
```

Answer (score 19):

I managed to do this in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/<Filename>.html`, but the solution should work in the `Magento_Checkout` as well.

When you inspect the `window` variable in the dev-console of your browser, you will see that the `checkout` and `checkoutConfig` objects are available on checkout-pages.

Here are the relevant parts:

```
checkout.baseUrl
checkout.checkoutUrl
checkout.customerLoginUrl
checkout.removeItemUrl
checkout.shoppingCartUrl
checkout.updateItemQtyUrl

checkoutConfig.cartUrl
checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl
checkoutConfig.defaultSuccessPageUrl
checkoutConfig.forgotPasswordUrl
checkoutConfig.pageNotFoundUrl
checkoutConfig.registerUrl
checkoutConfig.staticBaseUrl
```

In my case, I wanted to display an image; here's the code:

`<img data-bind="attr: {'src':checkoutConfig.staticBaseUrl + 'frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/<Locale>/images/logo.png'}" alt="" />`

Comment: It is useful for me.

Comment: Very useful man!

Comment: we can do like this also - 

<a class="action outline bordRad" data-bind="attr: {'href': window.BASE_URL}">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Back To Shopping'"></span>
</a>

Comment: very useful and the smartest answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Using **checkout** and **checkoutConfig** global variable, I couldn't able to get the baseUrl. What I did was,

1. I just added new global variable for **baseUrl** in my custom module `overriding \Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface getConfig()`.

It will look like,

```
$config['getBaseUrl'] = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
```

2. Now at checkout page, you should be able to get it like, 
   **window.checkoutConfig.getBaseUrl**.

In my case, I wanted to load it from **.html** file. The way I got the variable was,

```
<a data-bind="attr: {'href': checkoutConfig.getBaseUrl}" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: we can get the Base URL from the 'window' global variable also ------ "window.BASE_URL"

Answer (score 0):

Just for information.
From the answer of @simonthesorcerer,

```
checkout.baseUrl => {www.example.com}/

checkout.checkoutUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/

checkout.customerLoginUrl => {www.example.com}/customer/account/login/

checkout.removeItemUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/sidebar/removeItem/

checkout.shoppingCartUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/cart/

checkout.updateItemQtyUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/

checkoutConfig.cartUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/cart/

checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/

checkoutConfig.defaultSuccessPageUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/onepage/success/

checkoutConfig.forgotPasswordUrl => {www.example.com}/customer/account/forgotpassword/

checkoutConfig.pageNotFoundUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/noroute/

checkoutConfig.registerUrl => {www.example.com}/customer/account/create/

checkoutConfig.staticBaseUrl => {www.example.com}/pub/static/
```