# How to get Base Url in Checkout Html FIle in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, html, base-url

I have create a new step in checkout form Magento 2.

I want to get base Url in my .html file like **http://127.0.0.1/magento** How will i get that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean in html file for Knockout JS ?

Comment: Yes @AbdulPathan

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196157/77673

Answer (score 1):

> check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196157/85260) The Way Of Getting Base URL Inside KnockoutJS
> .html File